# Google map functionality is not working in Internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, internet-explorer

If I click on ‘+’ to see street name – Customers disappearing (and not appear any more regardless +/-)

Image : 
[image: Image2]

Comment: about which version of the IE are we talking here?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Internet Explorer to view Google maps, you might have some display problems. Internet Explorer has compatibility view, a feature that affects how maps may be displayed. To fix this, you can turn off Compatibility View.

For more refer : [Use Google Maps on Internet Explorer](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3118069?hl=en)